# Can anyone explain the difference between those two codes? And why does the second one work and the first doesn't?

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="red" onclick="dis()">
```

This is the first code of JavaScript:

```
function dis() {
  alert(this.name)
}
```

And here is the working version:

HTML:

```
  <input type="button" name="red" onclick="dis(this)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function dis(a) {
  alert(a.name)
}
```

Comment: In the first code, `this` refers to `Window` object whereas in second code, `this` refers to the element that is clicked. I'd suggest you to use third way `addEventListener`

Comment: Thanks it was more than helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

In first case you call `dis()` in global scope. And in this case `this` is global object

In second case you also call `dis()` in global scope. But you pass current `this` value as parameter to function.

To make first case work the same as second variant you should rewrite it like this:

```
<input type="button" name="red" onclick="dis.call(this)">
```

In this way you pass current `this` to function.

General rule for this is to look what is stands on the left side of function (another words - who is called function):

```
dis()     // -> on the left nothing stands, so `this` will correspond to global object
a.dis()   // -> on the left `a` stands, so `this` will correspond to `a`
new dis() // -> on the left `new` keyword stands, so `this` will correspond to newly created object
```